# Performance of Xamarin Forms CollectionViews on Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, collectionview

The CollectionViews on Xamarin are a really nice feature. Though, I am struggling to get a decent performance, when loading items. And this only happens on Android. It is slow and there is this flickering. Strangely, on iOS it works like a charm.

- The items have a grid, images (~15 Kb), labels buttons, about 9 visual elements
- Text, Images and Commands are bound to viewModel
- I'm using compiled bindings x:DataType=""

I am aware, that bindings are expensive. I've also tried AOT compilation. So, if anyone has some tips..

Thanks!

Comment: Have a play with [Threshold](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZq8K_64bc0), [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/populate-data#load-data-incrementally)

Answer (score 1):

While you haven't posted any code which makes it possibly for this to happen for any apparent reason, there is just one very likely answer - you are doing too much work on UI thread. That is likely to affect Android much more than iOS because of their different underlying architectures.